# Python: Running sequential and parallel tests at once

Tags: python, testing, pytest, mpi4py

I recently extended the scope of one of the functions of my python module so that it can be executed sequentially or in parallel (with mpi4py).

```py
def foo(param, use_mpi=False):
    pass
```

When I run my test by hand it works:

```
# (1) Sequentially
>>> python my_test_seq.py
# (2) In parallel
>>> mpirun -n 3 my_test_par.py
```

I've been using pytest so far and everything was fine until i wanted to add parallel tests.
Indeed, I can't find a way to launch the parallel test (2) with several processes. The only thing I managed to do is to run several pytests in parallel (thus running multiple times a test) but that doesn't meet my needs...

Does anyone know a way to do this ?

Comment: Check out https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/

Comment: @hoefling I know this package and use it to speedup running my test suite. I may be wrong but i don't think it can be used to solve my problem. What i want is:
1) to be able to run all my tests by sending sequential test on multiple CPU cores (compatible with pytest-xdist)
2) to be able to run my parallel tests while using multiple CPU cores for one parallel test (incompatible?)
To my knowledge, you can't tell pytest-xdist that a certain test will use three of the CPU cores.

Answer (score 1):

I've found two possible ways to do it:

1. Use pytest-mpi, a package which assists you with running tests when pytest is run under MPI, e.g. `$ mpirun -n 2 python -m pytest --with-mpi`. It provides simple markers to skip test that should no be run with mpi, or should have a minimum number of process required to run, ...
2. Use pytest_easyMPI, a package which aims at making MPI code testing as similar as possible to testing regular serial code. Using a decorator such as follow will allow you to mix serial and parallel code (run using 4 MPI ranks) in a same file:

```py
def foo_serial():
    pass

@mpi_parallel(4)
def foo_parallel():
    pass
```

The command used to launch my test is then `pytest --pyargs my_package`

I'm going to use pytest_easyMPI since since it allows me to run my serial and parallel tests transparently. Moreover it seems to be compatible with pytest-xdist! If I ever have a negative feedback to give, I will modify or add a comment to my answer.

Comment: pytest_easyMPI seems to work beautifully

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytest
import time

@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group1")
def test_case1():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Parallel Test Case 1")

@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group1")
def test_case2():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Parallel Test Case 2")

@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group1")
def test_case3():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Parallel Test Case 3")

@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group1")
@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_case4():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Parallel Test Case 4")

@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group1")
@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_case5():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Parallel Test Case 5")

@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group2")
@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_case6():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Parallel Test Case 6")

@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group2")
def test_case7():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Parallel Test Case 7")

@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group2")
def test_case8():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Parallel Test Case 8")

@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group2")
def test_case9():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Parallel Test Case 9")

@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group2")
def test_case10():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Parallel Test Case 10")
```

Now Run tests using `--dist loadgroup`

```
pytest --html=report.html -n auto --dist loadgroup -m smoke
```

We can see Tests in Group1 run sequential and Tests in Group2 run sequential but parallel to each other.

If we don't mark groups ,all tests will run parallel in different workers.

Comment: I think you may have gotten the question wrong. It was more about how to make the test run with `MPI`, not on available workers as whole units. From the doc, the `xdist_group` mark guarantees that all tests with same `xdist_group` name run in the same worker.